# Invalid stored block lengths. Jython and requests library

Tags: python, python-2.7, jython, burp, jython-2.7

Im currently building a burp extension and Im having some trouble integrating Jython (Burp is in java so Jython is required) and the requests library.

The idea of the extension is to check wether some URLS (By adding and endpoint) return certaing text in the response body.

Im doing something along the lines of the following:

```
endpoints = ['a','b','c','d','e']

#I have a list of str urls

for URL in urlList:
    for endpoint in endpoints
        newURL = URL + endpoint + '?query={%0A%20%20%0A}'

        getResponse = requests.get(newURL)
        postResponse = requests.post(newURL)
        getResponseText = getResponse.text
        postResponseText = postResponse.text

        if ("Very specific error" in getResponseText):
            getEndpointFound = True

        if ("Very specific error" in postResponseText):
            postEndpointFound = True
```

Whats weird is that the first url that comes through works fine, but the second one gives the following error

```
getResponse = requests.get(newURL)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 686, in send
    r.content
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 828, in content
    self._content = b''.join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or b''
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 750, in generate
    for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 750, in generate
    for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 560, in stream
    for line in self.read_chunked(amt, decode_content=decode_content):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 766, in read_chunked
    decoded = self._flush_decoder()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 408, in _flush_decoder
    return buf + self._decoder.flush()
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\BurpExtender\jython-standalone-2.7.1.jar\Lib\zlib.py", line 244, in flush
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\BurpExtender\jython-standalone-2.7.1.jar\Lib\zlib.py", line 281, in _get_inflate_data
zlib.error: java.util.zip.DataFormatException: invalid stored block lengths
```

At first I thought it was a problem regarding the URL list, so I tried giving a single URL. The error still ocurred.

It seems its happening when I try to do several requests, but I have no idea what really is going on, any idea on what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the thread is pretty old, but my team just faced the same issue.

Looks like there is some kind of issue with **zlib** in **jython**, and that means we have *compressed* response.

The trick is that **urllib3** adds `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate` by default, so a server is allowed to send compressed response, which causes the trouble.

We just added `headers={'accept-encoding':None}` as a workaround and it works well.