# zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid block type while decompressing .gzip with python

Tags: python, numpy, http, gzip, urllib3

I am trying to decompress `.gzip` file into `.xlsx` with NumPy.

I am using Python3.10.9, Numpy 1.23.5, and running the lines on VS Code.

My system is Win64.

However, I got these error code. I'm not sure how to solve this.

```
  File "c:\Users\USER\Folder\file.py", line 219, in <module>
    _, _, _, _, _, _, _, wdir = read_windsat_averaged_v8(filename) ###Error Occured
  File "c:\Users\USER\Folder\file.py", line 47, in read_windsat_averaged_v8
    data = np.frombuffer(f.read(), dtype=np.uint8) #Exception has occurred: error
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\gzip.py", line 301, in read
    return self._buffer.read(size)
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\_compression.py", line 118, in readall
    while data := self.read(sys.maxsize):
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\gzip.py", line 496, in read
    uncompress = self._decompressor.decompress(buf, size)
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid stored block lengths
```

These are my code, where the error occured:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import openpyxl
import gzip
import shutil

xscale = [0.15, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.01, 0.1, 0.2, 1.5] # A list of scaling factors for each variable.
offset = [-3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] # A list of offsets for each variable.
xdim = 1440 # The x-dimension of the data.
ydim = 720 # The y-dimension of the data.
numvar = 8 # The number of variables in the data.\

...

if data_file.endswith('.gz'):
        with gzip.open(data_file, 'rb') as f:
            data = np.frombuffer(f.read(), dtype=np.uint8) ### Error occured.
```

I use the function `print(data.size)` to get the size of the ndarray. It's 8294400.
I tried to reshape it into (8, 1440, 720), but it still did not work. And I got the same error code again.

I have read the [Official Manuals of Numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html), and I am not sure how should I do to solve it.

Actually I have used the same code to decompress the other chunk of data successfully, and I did not sure how to solve this. [One of the articles online](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1533) suggests this might happened because the `.gzip` file is broken. However, even though I redownloaded the .gzip file, it still did not work. Is there any solution?

This is my first time asking question on StackOverflow, and I hope I am describing it clearly. If not, I'd like to know how I can improve it.

Here is a link to the file: https://data.remss.com/windsat/bmaps_v07.0.1/y2016/m08/wsat_20160801v7.0.1_d3d.gz

From the starting, I download it with `urllib3.request()`, and I found that this problem may cause by the default setting of urllib3.
[See this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58189324/invalid-stored-block-lengths-jython-and-requests-library)
However, even though I change the line `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate` to `Accept-Encoding: None` manually, it still does not work.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the gzip file?

Comment: @MarkAdler Sure. [Here it is.](https://data.remss.com/windsat/bmaps_v07.0.1/y2016/m08/wsat_20160801v7.0.1_d3d.gz)

Comment: Nothing wrong with the file. It's a valid gzip stream.

Comment: @MarkAdler Thanks for helping me check this. I am trying to get new ways to solve it.

Comment: Your code gives me no error with that file.